# Get install app information

Tags: android

> How can I find all information of install for ex:  if my mobile has “angry birld”  then I   >want to get appname, packagename, versionname, versionname, date ,icon etc…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go through is might help you http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon